# Do we have procedure details in snowflake.account_usage schema

Tags: function, metadata, procedure, information-schema

I could see there is a separate `FUNCTION` view and `PROCEDURE` view in the information schema of databases. While in Snowflake.account_usage schema, the `FUNCTION` view have both Functions and Procedure details. What I observed is we do not have it as separate views.

My question is how can I filter out only Procedures from the `FUNCTION` view in `Snowflake.account_usage` schema? Is there any column that differentiates this?